# Creating a handler function with Bind to handle clicked menu item - wxWidgets 3.0

Tags: c++, events, menu, wxwidgets, menuitem

I would like to know how to use Bind function to create a simple event handler in wxWidgets 3.0 , C++.

To start off my experimenting I have created a very simple application - a main frame with a menu and a couple of items in the menu. No problems so far, all appears as expected. A part of the code I used was :

```
//create a menu bar
wxMenuBar* mbar = new wxMenuBar();

wxMenu* fileMenu = new wxMenu(_T(""));

fileMenu->Append(item1, _("&Item_1"), _("Select item 1"));
mbar->Append(fileMenu, _("&File"));
```

Now I would like to create a simple handler using Bind, that would pop out a message box in the event of selecting Item_1 from the menu, for example :

```
wxMessageBox( "You have selected Item 1", "Your selection", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION );
```

Please note that the popping up of a message box was just a simple example I have chosen to quickly grasp the concept and see the result. If possible, I would like the Bind event handler to be as general as possible, for arbitrary events and actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#define item1 (wxID_HIGHEST + 1)

class CApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() {
        // Create the main frame.
        wxFrame * frame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "demo");
        // Create a menu bar.
        wxMenuBar* mbar = new wxMenuBar();
        wxMenu* fileMenu = new wxMenu(_T(""));
        fileMenu->Append(item1, _("&Item_1"), _("Select item 1"));
        mbar->Append(fileMenu, _("&File"));
        frame->SetMenuBar(mbar);
        // Bind an event handling method.
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
        frame->Bind(wxEVT_MENU, &CApp::item1_OnMenu, this, item1);
#else
        frame->Bind(wxEVT_MENU, [](wxCommandEvent & evt)->void{
            wxMessageBox("You have selected Item 1", "Your selection", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
        }, item1);
#endif
        // Enter the message loop.
        frame->Show(true);
        return this->wxApp::OnInit();
    }
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
protected:
    void item1_OnMenu(wxCommandEvent & evt) {
        wxMessageBox("You have selected Item 1", "Your selection", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
    }
#endif
};
DECLARE_APP(CApp)
IMPLEMENT_APP(CApp)
```

The method `wxEvtHandler::Bind` has 3 overloads. The above only demonstrates 2 of them.

For the available event types, which will be the 1st param of `Bind`, please refer to wx/event.h. The event.h also tells us which event class should be used. For example,

```
#define EVT_MENU(winid, func) wx__DECLARE_EVT1(wxEVT_MENU, winid, wxCommandEventHandler(func))
```

note the `wxCommandEventHandler`, remove the suffix `Handler` and the remaining will be the event class `wxCommandEvent`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very well written. This topic is very confusing to me, even with your answer and a simple example that I have chosen. I don't yet understand events and what some declarations are meaning ( wxEVT_MENU in Bind, or evt in handler function,... ). And it's quite scary to think what to do when I come to more complicated controls and widgets =))

Comment: To make the long story short, when wxWidgets needs to find an "event handling method/function" for a wxEvent object, it checks the item in the "event handler chain" of the wxEvtHandler object one by one. An event handler chain consists of one or many wxEvtHandler objects. Each wxEvtHandler object has a "(per-instance) dynamic event table" and "static (per-class) event tables". The dynamic event table will be checked first. What Bind does is to add an entry into the dynamic event table.

Comment: BTW, all wxEvent objects travel past wxAppConsole::HandleEvent. So, adding a breakpoint in the method and stepping in and out may help you understand how the framework works.

Comment: Your example works very well for me. But I have a problem with Quit button in menu. I can't make it work to actually quit the application. Can you please add a comment or expand your answer to explain me how to do that ? Thank you.

Comment: There is no menu item "Quit" in the above example. If you want to close the main frame, you need to call method `Close` inherited from `wxWindow`, which sends a event type `wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW` to the event handler chain of the main frame itself, of which the handling method is `OnCloseWindow` by default, and the default behavior of `OnCloseWindow` is to `Destroy` itself. What the `Destroy` means to the main frame is to let the wxWidgets decide when to actually `delete` it, usually after the related event queue is empty.

Comment: Microsoft hasn't updated their __cplusplus define.  Even Visual Studio 2015 (CTP 6) defines __cplusplus as 199711L.  Microsoft has been notified about it for quite a while.  If you want to check for c++11 support on VS, you have to also include checking on if _MSC_VER is defined, and if so, what version started supporting the c++11 feature you're looking for.